# React Context API consumption and re-rendering using custom useContext hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-context

I am new to web development and was trying my luck with React.js.

I started exploring the Context API where I realised that re-renders (if mounted)/update happens when a component is subscribed to a context and the value of the context is changed.

So I tried understanding the situation by writing some snippets, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-demonstration-iov58?file=/src/fridgeContext.js) is the full code-base.

In the example, I created two components (`BucketVegies.jsx` and `BucketFruits.jsx`) with a common parent (`Fridge.jsx`)

Then I created two context, `ContextVegies` and `ContextFruits` with their own providers and consumers. I exposed the consumers using custom hooks (`useVegiesContext` and `useFruitsContext`)

**My Question is:**

*Why are sibling components re-rendering upon changing the values in either of the context? From what I read, only the component subscribed to a context must re-render/update when only its context values is changed. (In our example we "add" an item on button click hence change of value)*

Comment: Tried using `react-memo` or similar? Got answer? I tried separating the provider to sibling. Doesn't work.

Comment: I did not pursue it further as it was more of an optimisation activity, but would love any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleAddFruits = useCallback(() => {
    setFruits(fruits=>[...fruits, `Fruit${fruits.length + 1}`]);
  },[]);
  const handleAddVegies = useCallback(() => {
    setVegies(vegies=>[...vegies, `Vegie${vegies.length + 1}`]);
  },[]);
const vegiesValue=useMemo(()=>({ vegies, handleAddVegies }),[vegies,handleAddVegies])
const fruitsValue=useMemo(()=>({ fruits, handleAddFruits }),[fruits,handleAddFruits])
  return (
    <ContextVegies.Provider value={vegiesValue}>
      <ContextFruits.Provider value={fruitsValue}>
        {children}
      </ContextFruits.Provider>
    </ContextVegies.Provider>
```

This solved the issue in the `FridgeContext`.

If you want to try this library, [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices), it makes working with context fast and easy. You can do it like this with this library:

```
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices"
export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  count: {initialArg: 0},
  // rest of slices of Context you want to define
})
```

```
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"
const App = () => {
  const [count, useCount] = useSlice("count")
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count}
  </>
}
```